# Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'API_PUBLIC_KEY' has already been declared

Tags: angular

After adding Routes to my app-routing.module.ts , whenever i am using a routerLink, for example

`<a class="button" routerLink = "/">Home</a>`

I get this message in console :

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'API_PUBLIC_KEY' has already been declared** // VM2601 layout.js:1

inside the VM2601 layout.js:1 this line is marked as the problem

"`const API_PUBLIC_KEY = "xxxxxxxxx";`"
(where xxxxxxxxx is a key that i replaced with x s for privacy reasons).

Mind that this error is not affecting my apps functionality. I'm just trying to understand what causes it, how serious it is and ways to fix it.